# How to transfer just theme with picture in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Peace be upon you,
I want to ask you, I made a mini-project on WordPress, and because it is a weak computer, I bought a computer and the problem is that I want to transfer only that theme that I made with pictures, no change, but I do not know
When moving an entire WordPress folder, this message appears "Error establishing a database connection"
Can you help, thank you ❤️

Comment: This question is not related to programming, you may have better luck at [su].

Answer (score 1):

Where are you moving the entire Wordpress folder, are you moving it on the server. From what I understand your database is not setup on server.

Please go onto wp-config.php and setup your credentials.